# WCF configuration - Custom authentication on the host

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcf-security

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now - I cannot get this WCF service configured correctly to use a custom membership provider. When I fire up the test client I get this error:

> The username/password Membership provider MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.Business.UserAuthentication specified in the configuration is invalid. No such provider was found registered under system.web/membership/providers.

I have been following this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) to no avail. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here's my web.config:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <configuration>
>   <connectionStrings>
> <add name="MyCS" connectionString="Data Source=my server;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
>   </connectionStrings>
>   <system.web>
> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
>   </system.web>
>   <system.serviceModel>
> <bindings>
>   <wsHttpBinding>
>     <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
>       <security>
>         <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
>       </security>
>     </binding>
>   </wsHttpBinding>
> </bindings>
> <services>
>   <service name="MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.MembersService" behaviorConfiguration="Service_Behaviour">
>     <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
>       name="basicHttpBinding" contract="MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.IMembersService" />
>     <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
>       name="wsHttpBinding" contract="MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.IMembersService" />
>     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
>   </service>
> </services>
> <behaviors>
>   <serviceBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="Service_Behaviour">
>       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
>       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
>       <serviceCredentials>
>         <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
>           membershipProviderName="MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.Business.UserAuthentication" />
>       </serviceCredentials>
>     </behavior>
>   </serviceBehaviors>
> </behaviors>
> <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"     aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
>   </system.serviceModel>
>   <system.webServer>
>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
>   </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```

My user authentication class is as follows:

```
public class UserAuthentication : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var db = new PetaPoco.Database("MyDB");

        db.Fetch<dynamic>("SELECT Username, Password FROM MyTable WHERE Username=@0 AND Password =@1",
                             userName, password);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the link that you have provided mentions customUserNamePasswordValidatorType to specify custom authentication type, UserAuthentication in your case. I think MembershipProviderName should be a class derived from MembershipProvider Class.

Comment: try to change membershipProviderName="MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.Business.UserAuthentication" to customUserNamePasswordValidatorType ="MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.Business.UserAuthentication"

Comment: this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731315.aspx mentions attributes of <userNameAuthentication> element. 
See if you have not already.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I now get this error: Could not load type 'MidlandsCoop.MembersWcfService.Business.UserAuthentication' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Solved! Just needed to add the namespace after the type name. Thanks!